# How can I Fetch child data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

I have a JSON node who have Articles, and that Articles are writer by a user, I want know how to Fetch data from that User, because I need to show a Profile Picture and your Name:

Here is my API call Method:

```
getItems() {
        this.setState({ 'isLoading': true });

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/article/')
            .then(results => {
                if (results.ok) {
                    return results.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
                }
            })
            .then(results => this.setState({ 'items': results, 'isLoading': false }))
            .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
    }
```

Here is my JSON:

```
Article:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Obama Offers Hopeful Vision While Nothing Nation's Fears",
        "description": "Obama Offers Hopeful Vision While Nothing Nation's Fears",
        "category": 1,
        "user": 1,
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/article_image/news_01_JvEyD6u.jpg"
    }
]

User:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Jefferson",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/profile_image/Perfil2_1WziFGt.jpg"
    }
]
```

It's what I have:

```
<div>
    <Thumbnail src={item.image} />
    <h3>{item.title}</h3>
    <div>{item.user}</div>
</div>
```

I tried to use "item.user.image" but that comes null.

[image: I need that result]

Comment: Are these two json files within your app?  Can you show what you've tried to get the output you need?

Comment: I edited the question thanks

Comment: 'fetching' generally means doing an api call but my understanding is that you already got the Article and User array. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly you're trying to associate the user with the article. Without fetching the user data you could achieve this by finding the user in dr `User` `Array` by calling `User.find()`

**example**

```
const foundUser = User.find(user => user.id === item.user);

<p>{foundUser.image}</p>
```

Assuming `item` is the Article holder a `user` property with the id.

**an other approach**

If you are the one in control of the api it may be a good idee to return the userdata as a nested property with the `Articles`.  This of course depends on the project, scale, amount of data, personal opinion and what not.

Comment: Can I get this information dynamically? Because I have several articles on one page

Comment: If you already got all the users in state you could easily do something like { this.state.users.find(user => user.id === item.id).image }. In your jsx. But personally I would extract it to a helper function. But you could try this first, taking small steps in better then taking no steps at all